# Capitalize first character of each word - Help finding my mistake

Tags: c++, stream, capitalize

Lets assume we have a text file called text.txt. In this text.txt file we find these 3 lines:

```
test meow, hello one, two, 
ten eleven
obelix, new
```

Now i am just trying to capitalize the first character of each word, so it should look like this:

```
Test Meow, Hello One, Two, 
Ten Eleven
Obelix, New
```

My code is doing this, but only with 1 mistake which i cant find.
The last cout is giving me only the following content:

```
Obelix, New
```

So everything before is missing. Can you guys try to explain me where i did my mistake? I Hope the german comments dont confuse you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

struct fileInformation
{
    string sDatei;
    string sPfad;
    string sText;
    int iStringMAX;
    char cZeichen;

}fileinformation;

ifstream inFile;

cout << "Dateiname: ";
cin >> fileinformation.sDatei;
cout << "Pfad: ";
cin >> fileinformation.sPfad;

fileinformation.sPfad.append("\\");
fileinformation.sPfad.append(fileinformation.sDatei);

inFile.open(fileinformation.sPfad);

if (inFile.is_open()) 
{
    while (getline(inFile, fileinformation.sText))
    {
        cout << fileinformation.sText <<endl;
    }
    //Anzahl der Zeichen
    fileinformation.iStringMAX = fileinformation.sText.size();
}
else
{
    cerr << "Problem vorhanden" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

for (int i = 0; i < fileinformation.iStringMAX; i++)
{
    if (i == 0)
    {   
        //Erstes Zeichen vom String in Character Variable speichern (Vorher auf Großbuchstabe)
        //Tausche Kleinbuchstaben gegen unser Großbuchstaben aus
        fileinformation.cZeichen = toupper(fileinformation.sText[i]);
        fileinformation.sText[i] = fileinformation.cZeichen;
    }
    else if (isspace(fileinformation.sText[i]))
    {
        fileinformation.cZeichen = toupper(fileinformation.sText[i + 1]);
        fileinformation.sText[i + 1] = fileinformation.cZeichen;
    }

}


cout << fileinformation.sText;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: *but only with 1 mistake which i cant find* -- Use your debugger, just like we would have to do to solve the problem.

Comment: `toupper(fileinformation.sText[i + 1])`  So what happens on the last iteration of the loop?  This looks like an out-of-bounds access.

Comment: I'm surprised this code have just one problem. Divide & conquer your big problems into multiple trivial tasks; then you can check each task input/output and localize where's the quirk.

Comment: You should not use SO as a debugging service for badly written code. Your problem is that you use functions from the standard library w/o knowing what they do. Have a look at what [`getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) does.

Answer (score 2):

Everytime you read line of text from the input file you overwrite fileinformation.sText with this line. Afterwards you do your capitalization on this last line and this last line is printed out. You need to store every line you read from file.

```
istream& getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
Note that any content in str before the call is replaced by the newly extracted sequence.
```